# Jasmine test not passing when function returning correct result

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Have a simple function which is returning a value:

```
obj.id = function(id) {
    if (!id) {
        throw new Error('obj.id: no param');
    } else if (typeof(id) === 'string') {
        return obj.doc.getElementById(id);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

running my test:

```
it('Should return null if passed parameter is not a string', function() {
    expect(function() {
        obj.id({});
    }).toBeNull();
});
```

Test fails to pass even though it should be a pass.

```
it('Should throw an error if no parameter is passed in', function() {
    expect(function() {
        obj.id();
    }).toThrow(new Error('obj.id: no param'));
});
```

This one passes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `{}` as a variable to the `id` function.  Even though the object has no keys, an empty object evaluates to `true` when used in an `if` condition

You can prove this using something like this:

```
({}) ? console.log('not falsey') : console.log('falsey');
// -> outputs 'not falsey'
```

Maybe you can use the `hasOwnProperty()` function instead?

```
({}.hasOwnProperty()) ? console.log('not empty') : console.log('empty');
// -> outputs 'empty'
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this with the following

```
expect(wh.id({})).to.be.null
```

Test passed as required.